# Firing event function without an event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to reuse a function that is fired from an event binding.

This issue is caused from browsers remembering checkbox states, so I have to fire the function on document ready.

I know I could put `setGrid()` in an anonymous function and pass in the element instead, but that would make it difficult to unbind the specific event.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="grid" id="checkbox-grid">
```

Javascript:

```
function setGrid(e) {

  var $this = $(e.target); // "error: e is undefined" on situation 2

  if( $this.is(':checked') ){
       // do something if checkbox is checked
  }
  else{
       // do something if checkbox isn't
  }
}

// 1. event binding
$('#checkbox-grid').on('change', setGrid);

// 2. function fired on page ready
setGrid();
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're using `e.target` instead of `this`?

Comment: Can we see the rest of that function? It may be important to know what it's doing.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Not really, force of habit. But in situation 2, `this` would still be undefined, right?

Comment: well a basic thing would be to remember that if you do not pass anything to the function, e would be undefined and when you try to access `e.target` you are trying to access a non existetn member of an undefined object. pass a null like this: `setGrid(null);` and inside assign `var $this = $(e.target);` only if `e!=null`

Comment: @PaulSham It would be the window object actually, but there are ways to set what `this` is when a function is called with `call`, `apply` or `bind`.  However, @artofcode has a better answer with trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the first solution you have. Since you're using jQuery, it's dead easy to fire the function, you just fire the event it's associated with. So:

```
$('#checkbox-grid').on('change', setGrid);    // to set it up; then
$('#checkbox-grid').trigger("change");        // fires the change event of the
// checkbox, so fires the function.
```

You can do it with any event, just substitute `change` for the event. However, since you're probably doing it with `change` for a reason, it may be best to leave it like that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes so much sense. I already do this for click events, but for some reason, I thought triggering change would actually change the state of the checkbox. Thanks!